# SwiftUI Textfield Alert for macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, alert, textfield

Is it possible (also with detours via `AppKit`) to create text field alerts for `macOS` in `SwiftUI`? I found several tutorials on how to do that with `UIKit` for `iOS` but you can't use these solutions for `macOS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SwiftUI 4 it is now possible to simply add a `TextField` to the `.alert()` modifier like you would do this with a `Button`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State private var input = ""

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            showingAlert = true
        }
        .alert("Enter your Name", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            TextField("Your Name", text: $input)
            Button("OK") { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work if you want the button to perform an action. Try entering `print("Done")` in the closure of the button: it will not print if there is a TextField in the alert.

Comment: @HunterLion I tested it with Swift Playgrounds for iPad and it works fine! Did you test it in Xcode Simulator? Because that doesn’t work… Or maybe it’s a bug with Xcode 14.2…

Comment: @SwiftIsGreat: I guess you are right for iPad, but this is a macOS app, unfortunately it is not working on a my Mac-Intel. I have [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74837671/swiftui-textfield-alert-for-macos-button-does-not-perform-action) in this regard.

Comment: I also tried it in Xcode on my m1 MacBook Air and it works fine too, so maybe it is a problem with Intel Macs.